# How do I import Amazon EC2 instance/user data into the environments of the services on my machine?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, init-script, amazon-ec2, upstart

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.10; so my init system can be either upstart or systemd.

Things like [How to set an environment variable in Amazon EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28643573/) over on Stack Overflow show how one fetches an instance ID using `curl`, then fetches instance tags using `aws ec2 describe-tags`, then imports them as environment variables into an interactive shell, or a shell script.  One of the answers also shows how one runs those data though `jq`.

This is all well and good, but I don't need variables set in a shell script, or in an interactive shell.  Having a shell script that is `source`d as in those answers is no good to me, as there isn't a shell involved in where I need these things set.

I need them set in the environments of dæmon processes that are started from systemd or upstart.  In the systemd case, in particular, service unit files are not shell scripts *at all*.  To set environment variables one puts things like `Environment=` in the unit file.

So how can I create the last link in the chain?  With what's on Stack Overflow I can get as far as reading the data and making environment-like `var=val` strings out of them.  (I am actually reading [instance metadata and user data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) but the principle is the same — I pull stuff with `curl` and then do the `jq` and other post-processing to make `var=val` out of it.)

How do I forge the final link in the chain and get these strings into the environments of specific services run by upstart and systemd?

Comment: I see that this is already sinking.  Here; allow me.

Comment: Unless your init system is replacing an already running init system you will not have networking available to allow you to fetch something from a url

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the strings in a file in the form of *environment variable assignments*, e.g.

```
SOME_NAME=some_value
```

then you could perhaps use the `EnvironmentFile=` setting in the unit file. More details in `man systemd.exec`.

And you could always replace the service you're starting with a script that first sources a file with the environment variable settings, then `exec`s the original service. This should work with upstart too.

For example:

```
#!/bin/sh
. /some/where/environment-variable-settings-file
exec original-service "$@"
```